# Enable mod_rewrite using ebextensions file in Elastic Beanstalk CLI

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, octobercms, ebcli

I am installing OctoberCMS on my production server using Elastic Beanstalk CLI. I have created a folder called `.ebextensions` and created a container command for `php artisan october:up`. But I am getting an error as

```
The "/var/app/ondeck/storage/cms/combiner" directory does not exist.
container_command 01-migrations in .ebextensions/02-deploy.config failed. For more detail, check /var/log/eb-activity.log using console or EB CLI.
```

I have tried most of the options provided by unable to find a solution for the same. The following is the code snippet.

```
files:          
  "/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf": 
     mode: "644"
     owner: root
     group: root
     content: |
       AllowOverride All

container_commands:
    09writable_dirs:
        command: "chmod -R 775 /var/app/ondeck/storage"
    01-migrations:
        command: "php artisan october:up"
```

As `mod_rewrite` is not enabled my further migrations are not seeded. Any help would be highly appreciated.